# WSE 3.0 WSE839 Exception

Tags: c#, soap, mtom, wse, wse3.0

There is a Java-Soap-Service which I want to call with WSE 3.0, I generated a Proxy with the WSDL-File but the service expects MTOM for it´s data.
I also followed this tutorial and it worked well but didn´t helped:
http://twit88.com/blog/2008/05/14/net-mtom-enabled-your-application-using-wse/

The Exception I get is:

```
System.FormatException: "WSE839: An HTTP response was received that used the following content type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8. The following content type was expected: multipart/related; type=application/xop+xml."
```

I know WSE 3.0 is obsolete if there is an other way to do it please tell.

Can some one please help?

Comment: WSE is ancient, do you have to use it? Looking at the comments under the linked article, getting MTOM to work properly with WSE may be impossible.

Comment: No, I don't have to. Can you tell me how to do it otherwise?

Comment: I suggest you use wcf, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/mtom-encoding) for a code sample to get you started. Be aware though that sometimes getting soap messaging to work between java and .net can be a real PITA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your generated classes base class from System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol to Microsoft.Web.Services3.WebServicesClientProtocol.  Once that is done you will be able to access a field called RequireMtom.  Set this to true prior to calling any method that needs to send MTOM.  Make sure to disable it for non MTOM calls.